# Обновление эффектов влияния на тайловом поле

Tags: c#, разработка-игр

Делаю игру с полем из клеток, каждая клетка может хранить в себе определенных персонажей, многие из которых дают соседям различные эффекты, своих усиливают, вражеских наоборот (бафы/дебафы), таким же образом некоторые из них воздействуют на сами клетки.

Пока для этого используется `List<Buff>` с подпиской на разнообразные события (уничтожение, дезактивация персонажей etc). Все это работает, но громоздко и неудобно (с одной утечкой памяти стольких событий только боролся до очешуения)/

Есть несколько вопросов. Например, если персонажа ставят в зоне влияния какого-то другого персонажа, то эффект от последнего проявится на следующий цикл обновления эффектов, а хотелось бы сразу же, но запускать алгоритм от устанавливаемо персонажа, который запросит от соседей их эффекты кажется не лучшей идей. Как лучше всё это организовать?

Код:

```
public class Buff
{
    public BuffTargetEnum TargetStat { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public GemBase OwnerGem { get; set; }

    public Buff(int value, GemBase buffOwner, BuffTargetEnum buffType)
    {
        Value = value;
        OwnerGem = buffOwner;
        TargetStat = buffType;
    }

    public Buff()
    {
    }

    public override string ToString() =>
        $"{TargetStat.GetId()} {OwnerGem?.Owner?.Name} {Value}";
}
```

Базовый класс для персонажей и клеток:

```
public abstract class GridEntity
{
            //BuffList потомок List<Buff> где в методах Add/Remove
    //реализована подписка/отписка на события от персонажей и прочее служебное
    //в т.ч. делегат обновления

    public abstract BuffList Buffs { get; set; }        /*прочие поля и код*/
}

public class Cell: GridEntity
{
    public IGame Game; //
    public CharacterBase CurrentChar { get; set; }


    private CharBase.CharDestroyHandler _destroyCharHandler;

    public Cell(IPlayer owner, Point point, IGame gs)
    {
        Buffs = new BuffList();
        CellPoint = point;
        Game = gs;
        _destroyCharHandler = g =>
        {
            CurrentChar.Destroy -= _destroyCharHandler;
            CurrentChar = null;
        };

    }

    public void AddChar(CharTypeEnum type, IPlayer owner)
    {
        if (CurrentChar != null) return;

        var newChar = CharFactory.CreateChar(this, owner, type);
        newChar.Destroy += _destroyCharHandler;
        CurrentChar = newChar;
        CurrentChar.UpdateLevel();
        CurrentChar.Action();
    }
}
```

Базовый класс для персонажей:

```
public class CharBase: GridEntity
{
    public Cell ParentCell { get; set; }
    public delegate void CharDestroyHandler(CharBase cb);
    public event CharDestroyHandler Destroy;
    public event CharDestroyHandler RemoveBuffs;
    public IPlayer Owner;
    public string GemId { get; set; } //это сокращенное имя для передачи через WebSocket
    protected IGame Game => ParentCell?.Game;

    protected CharBase(Cell parentCell, IPlayer owner) 
    {
        Owner = owner;
        ParentCell = parentCell;
        Buffs = new BuffList(() =>{ CheckLive();UpdateLevel();}); //При изменении бафов сработает этот делегат, 
                                                                  //проверяющий некоторые условия, например убьет персонажа
                                                                  //Если его раны станут больше чем возможное здоровье
                                                                  //после снятия бафа на здоровье
    }

    public abstract void CharAction(Cell target);

    public void ResetBuffs() //Переустановка всех бафов
    {
        if (this.IsFist() || this is Bomb || this is Vampire) return; //боевые персонажи не делают бафов
        RemoveBuff?.Invoke(this); //удаляем все бафы
        if (Game != null) CharAction(null); //и ставим их по новой
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Destroy?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Пример одного из персонажей

```
public sealed class SleepChar : CharBase
{
    public SleepChar(Cell parentCell, IPlayer owner) : base(parentCell, owner)
    {
        CharId = GemTypeEnum.Sleep.GetId();
    }

    protected override void _gemAction(Cell targetCell)
    {
        #region description
        // Сон(рабочее название). Небоевой/дебафф, элемент - ВОЗДУХ. Те кристаллы и клетки противника, на которые распространяется
        // влияние кристалла «Сон» теряют возможность использования своего эффекта до момента уничтожения кристалла «Сон».
        // Нельзя установить кристалл на клетку Земли.
        // Важное условие: кристалл «Сон» не может оказать влияние на клетки и кристаллы элемента ОГНЯ (ограничение во избежание «патовой»
        // ситуации).
        // Кристалл можно применить только 2 раза за игровую сессию.
        // Если любой кристалл попал в зону воздействия кристалла «Сон» то кристалл замораживается и не выполняет свою функцию, до
        // момента его вывода из-под влияния кристалла «Сон» путем уничтожения кристалла «Сон» или поворотом поля (если поворот выведет
        // кристалл из зоны влияния кристалла «Сон»).
        // Зона воздействия кристалла «Сон» зависит от уровня:
        // 1 уровень: «Линия»
        // 2уровень: «Крест»
        // 3уровень: «Квадрат»

        #endregion description

        var influence = (InfluenceEnum)Level;

        var targetCells = Game.GetTargetCellForBuff(ParentCell, influence); //получаем клетки на которые влияет персонаж;
        var buff = new Buff(0, this, BuffTargetEnum.Sleep); //создаем бафф
        foreach (var cell in targetCells)
        {
            var trgt = cell.HasChar() ? (GridEntity)cell.CurrentChar : cell; 
            if (trgt.Element == ElementEnum.Fire) continue; //Огонь не трогаем
            // навешиваем на объект баф сна если он не принадлежит игроку
            if (!trgt.Owner.Equals(Owner)) trgt.Buffs.Add(buff); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий. У вас есть конкретная проблема? "кажется не лучшей идей" - не является нормальным аргументом.

Comment: Так в том-то и проблема, что проблема архитектурная, с конкретикой я справлюсь, не хватает именно удачной абстрактной конструкции. Недостатки текущей: громоздко, слишком много ручной работы - добавить баф, подписаться на события, среагировать на события, отписаться от события. Да и добавление бафов - по сути ручной обход области влияния, и самое главное - если в область попадает новый объект, он не узнает об этом пока его источник не пробежится по окружающим. Все это очень не гибко, и очень хрупко.

Comment: у самой клетки событие, которое в момент изменения опрашивает себя и своих соседей, если есть, что менять изменяет и те объекты. У объектов соотвественно принадлежность клетке.

Comment: Что такое ручная работы в вашем понимании? Вы один раз написали метод, вызываете его когда и где надо, он все делает..

Comment: Извините, но вопрос реально нужно закрыть, потому что он слишком общий и неконкретный. У вас нет кода, есть только попытки что-то объяснить на пальцах. Помочь может либо показ исходников проекта целиком (а это с трудом влезет в метку инспекцию кода), либо чёткое изолирование вопроса с показом исходников. Вот [посмотрите](https://habrahabr.ru/post/322258/) исходники игры -- как всё чётко разложено по полочкам и как хорошо продумана архитектура. Попробуйте свой проект разбить на отдельные модули и так же структурировать.

Comment: Я могу код выложить, но его будет достаточно много даже если выкосить все детали не важные для вопроса. Но если это поможет - ок

Comment: Задавать вопросы и задавать вопросы хорошо - непростое дело. Написание минимально воспроизводимого примера требуется по правилам stackoverflow, вам же нужно хорошо продумать, что является важным для вопроса, а что нет. Я бы на вашем месте начал с пары классов и постепенно бы дописывал код (если и тот который попросят в комментариях) - а не наоборот, вывалить весь проект со словами "читайте".

Comment: Добавил немного кода. Максимально сократил.